# Why my tabbar was rendered with gray rect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

[image]

```
// Tabbar
// Icon inactive
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor darkGrayColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
// Icon active
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:PRIMARY_COLOR];
// Text active
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: PRIMARY_COLOR} forState:UIControlStateSelected];
// Background
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:WHITE_COLOR];
// Over View YES/NO
[[UITabBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
```

I've a gray rect around the text and the icon.
Why? Where my damn mistake?

[image]

Comment: It tried and this code works normally. Did you do any thing else with tabbar?

Comment: Hi @trungduc thanks for your answer, mmm no.  I've added these snippets on the appdelegate didFinishWithOptions, The images that I'm using are simply white with transparent background. Do you mean anything else?

Comment: Did you set images programmatically or inside Storyboard? If programmatically, can you show your code?

Comment: No, I've added them only in storyboard.

Comment: It's strange. Can you give me one in 4 images?

Comment: Sure, I add them into the topic.

Comment: No, i mean 1 in 4 png file you used

Comment: Check the image of tabbar, also the text has the background. I've added the image at the bottom of topic, but it's white.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159912/discussion-between-trungduc-and-ceccocq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion, we find that @CeccoCQ used another setting for `UIView`. That makes every view have a custom background color (in the image, it's gray color).

```
[[UIView appearance] setBackgroundColor:WINDOW_BACKGROUND_COLOR];
```

To resolve the problem, remove this custom setting and everything will work fine.